# Acessing refs with render props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-konva

I'm trying to deal with lifting up ref from child component.

My parent component:

```
import React, { Component, use } from "react";
import { Transformer } from "react-konva";

export default class SelectProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.shapeRef = React.createRef();
    this.trRef = React.createRef();
    this.setRef = this.setRef.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("mount");
  }

  setRef(ref) {
    this.shapeRef = ref;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.children({
          setRef: this.setRef,
        })}
        <Transformer ref={this.trRef} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

And child:

```
import React from "react";
import { Rect } from "react-konva";
import SelectProvider from "./TransformerProvider";

const RectangleShape = (props) => {
  return (
    <SelectProvider>
      {({ setRef }) => (
        <>
          <Rect ref={setRef} {...props}></Rect>
        </>
      )}
    </SelectProvider>
  );
};

export default RectangleShape;
```

Unfortunately my `shapeRef.current` is undefined during componentDidMount, and I don't really know what causes this behavior.

I will be pleased if someone explain me why is this happening. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `this.shapeRef = React.createRef();` to create a reference.

But inside `setRef` you are overwriting it:

```
setRef(ref) {
  this.shapeRef = ref;
}
```

After this commander `this.shapeRef` will refer to `Konva.Rect` instance. And an instance of `Konva.Rect` has no `current` property.

So you have two options:

1. Just use `this.shapeRef` instead of `this.shapeRef.current`
2. Or set reference correctly via `this.shapeRef.current = ref;`

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-firefly-bre9c?file=/src/index.js

Comment: This kind of helped me to solve an issue which I faced, in my case i had to keep the ref's in a context and in child when i click on shapes the transformer was not getting attached, the issue was the context was not getting updated with the current ref, what i did is onclick on shape i took the e.target and set shaperef.current = e.target, after this transformer started attaching to selected shapes, don't know whether this is the right way or not